# How can I delete files based on (flac) metadata?

Tags: bash, metadata, flac

I have several folders with both FLAC 24/96 and 16/44.1 files.

I want to delete the 24-bit/96 KHz files, but leave the others. How do I do this from the command line? Is there a way to systematically sort files by metadata and then use that list with `rm`?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, it's worth too mention that it's also very easy to open a directory and it's subdirectories in [Puddletag](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/puddletag/), sort for your desired criteria, and then mark and delete the files you want. This might be *safer* and even faster than customizing or writing a completely new script (see: [xkcd 1205 - Is It Worth the Time?](http://xkcd.com/1205/)).

---

You can use `metaflac` ([manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/metaflac.1.html)) for flac files.

```
$ metaflac --show-sample-rate --show-bps "somefile.flac"
44100
16
```

Of course this is not a complete script. You might want to take a look at the [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/).

The following would be a very basic script that deletes all files which return `44100` and `16` to the above command. The directory is given to the script as a parameter (e.g. `flac-44100-removal.sh "Music/All music with 44.1kHz/"`)

```bash
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\n'

for file in $(find "${1}" -name "*.flac");
do
    if [ "$(metaflac  --show-sample-rate "$file")" = "44100" ]; then
        if [ "$(metaflac  --show-bps "$file")" = "16" ]; then
            rm -i "$file"
        fi
    fi
done
```

Alternatives to metaflac are: `vorbiscomment` for ogg, `AtomicParsley` for mp4/m4a, `mid3v2` for mp3 or `mediainfo` for everything, but they all have different outputs, with mediainfo being overly customizable.

Comment: metaflac is exactly what I needed, thanks. But when I run the script you suggested (with 96000 and 24 instead of 44100 and 16), it throws the error FLAC__METADATA_CHAIN_STATUS_ERROR_OPENING_FILE. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Remove the doublequotes from `"$(find "${1}" -name *.flac)"`, this should work: `$(find "${1}" -name *.flac)`. With the qoutes all file adresses were concatenated into one long chain (string), not separated as they should have been.

Comment: Perfect. I also wrote a short script to write a list of 24-bit FLAC files (for future reference):  


`#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\n'

for file in $(find "${1}" -name *.flac);
do
    if [ "$(metaflac  --show-bps "$file")" = "16" ]; then
            echo "$file">output.txt
    fi
done`
Sorry for the terrible formatting.

Comment: I think it should be `>>output.txt` instead or you will only have one file in there. :)

Comment: You probably _don't_ want to look at the ABS, do you? `:D` Look: you're parsing the output of `find`... that terrible! It will bite you in the back as soon as a filename contains a newline.

Comment: Okay show us the worst possible exploit for this script that made you down vote this answer. I'm curious to learn. Searching for flac files which have 44100 Hz sampling rate and 16 bits per sample in root or your uefi firmware and trying to delete them **interactively** without administrative rights, yes I'm really curious to learn how to break things with that.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, @LiveWireBT. Not sure I understood gniourf, but I will definitely take a look at the ABS as soon as I have time.